# Is there some application to download files from popular file hosting websites?

Tags: software-recommendation, downloads

I was wondering if there are some applications for downloading files from some popular hosting websites, automating the procedure of waiting and fetching links and downloading files, once we give the applications the links?

Examples of such websites are

- Rapidshare,
- Uploading,
- Megaupload,
- Filesonic,
- Fileserver,
- Hotfiles,
- Depositefiles,
- iFile.

But the applications are not necessarily applicable to all of them.

Thanks and regards!

---

ADDED:

I just tried slimrat. It failed to download files from rapidshare. Can it be because the website of rapidshare has changed recently and the parsing functionality for their website by slimrat is not up-to-date yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[JDonwloader](http://jdownloader.org/) does exactly that - with some capthca skipping (that doesnt work on all sites)

Comment: Thanks! Is it in some repository that can be downloaded from synaptic application manager?

Comment: No, last time i downloaded from the website

Comment: @Tim There is a ppa for jdownloader:

- sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jre
- sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jd-team/jdownloader
- sudo apt-get update
- sudo apt-get install jdownloader

Answer (score 6):

## Plowshare

My favorite is [plowshare](https://github.com/mcrapet/plowshare/) -- see [here](https://github.com/mcrapet/plowshare/blob/master/INSTALL) for installation instructions.

It's a command-line tool, very fast and efficient (as opposed to JDownloader, which was always extremely slow for me, probably because it uses the Java VM).

### Example

```
plowdown http://www.mediafire.com/?9i282l2o6f27enw
Starting download (mediafire): http://www.mediafire.com/?9i48232o6f27enw
Leave this field blank and hit enter to get another captcha image
Enter captcha response (drop punctuation marks, case insensitive): example captcha
File URL: http://199.91.153.74/mg1jopw993tg/9i48232o6f27enw/Example.pdf
Filename: Example.pdf
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  180M  100  180M    0     0   125k      0  0:24:35  0:6:35 --:--:--  458k
Example.pdf
```

Note: captchas appear in a separeted window on the desktop using Image Magick.

> ### Features
>
> - plowshare supports many different websites through plugins.
> - A small footprint (few shell scripts). No JAVA. Run fast on embedded devices!
> - Few dependencies and portable. bash and curl are enough for most hosters.
> - Modules (site plugins) are simple to write using plowshare API.
> - Support for automatic online captcha solver services.

Source: https://github.com/mcrapet/plowshare/

Comment: Besides, it supports more than 80 hosting platforms

Answer (score 5):

Firefox has an add-on for that purpose, called [Skipscreen](https://addons.mozilla.org/nl/firefox/addon/skipscreen-incredible-rapidsha/).

[Description from AMO](https://addons.mozilla.org/nl/firefox/addon/skipscreen-incredible-rapidsha/):

> Skips unnecessary pages on sites like
>   Rapidshare, Megaupload, zShare,
>   Mediafire, and more. Try it out, or
>   watch a demo at
>   http://www.skipscreen.com
>
> Why click through ad-laden pages and
>   wait for countdowns when your computer
>   can do it for you

Answer (score 2):

[Tucan](http://www.tucaneando.com/) is very easy to use for this.

Answer (score 2):

[Free Rapid Downloader (FRD)](http://wordrider.net/freerapid/download.html) although still Java-based is much lighter than JDownloader.

It doesn't need install, just execute the frd.sh file.

Make it executable first - changing permissions in properties or fire in terminal `sudo chmod a+x path-of-frd.sh`. (copy `frd.sh` file and paste in place of `path-of-frd.sh` in this line)

If an error message keeps popping-up, ignore it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[**Fatrat**](http://fatrat.dolezel.info/) ([Click To Install](http://apt.marcoceppi.com/p/fatrat))

> FatRat is an open source download manager for Linux written in C++ and built on top of the Trolltech Qt 4 library. It is rich in features and is continuously extended.

It supports torrents as well.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The best Download-Manager i can think of is [pyload](http://www.pyload.org)

Its very lightwight, and perfect for Servers and multiple Users, because of its Web-UI.
It works flawless with every Hoster, Multi-OCH, decrypters and also external Programms like Flexget. It also works with Flashgot and has it's own Chrome-Plugin.

With the beautiful Web-UI of pyLoad 0.5, it's a lot way better than JDownloader ever will be