# What are some alternatives to jDownloader for 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, software-recommendation, jdownloader

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there some application to download files from popular file hosting websites?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31109/is-there-some-application-to-download-files-from-popular-file-hosting-websites)

I just added the JDownloader PPA and installed the app but when I launch the app I get a JUpdate box telling me to download which it never does so I'm looking for a  good lightweight alternative to JDownloader. Any help

Comment: try wget it's light and fast and it is installed by default on Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: yeah it is but it is not as automated with hosting sites as JDownloader the likes. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- For an alternative available in the repositories, try Tucan Manager `tucan`, although I haven't had a very good experience with it.
- For a lightweight GUI alternative, I highly recommend [FreeRapid](http://wordrider.net/freerapid/download.html) (it still uses Java)
- For a non-Java GUI, try [Pyload](http://pyload.org/download) (deb files available)
- If you are comfortable with the command-line, try [`plowshare`](https://github.com/mcrapet/plowshare/), also available from the `ppa:plowsharepackagers/ppa` PPA.

Answer (score 1):

What java are you using? I think only oracle java works with jdownloader.

Just in case if you want to try again with jdownloader.

Comment: The one in the Software Center

Answer (score 1):

[Free Rapid Downloader (FRD)](http://wordrider.net/freerapid/download.html) although still Java-based is a lot lighter than JD and can be used in Ubuntu.

It does not need installation, just execute the frd.sh file.

Make it executable first - changing permissions in properties or fire in terminal `sudo chmod a+x path-of-frd.sh`. (copy `frd.sh` file and paste in place of `path-of-frd.sh` in this line)

If there's an error message that keeps popping-up, ignore it's of no consequence.

[image]

From my experience Tucan it's by no means a good alternative (it never worked for me).

There is also [ochDownloader](http://ochdownloader.com/) (non-java, therefore very light) that I used in Windows and has a Linux version (but it needs compiling I guess, above my capacities).